# Update record in laravel shows not exist message ( Not Updating Record )

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have two separate APIs calls. One for click on edit page and another for update page:

The controller method when the user hits edit link:

```
public function EditList($page_id)
{
    $listEdit= DB::table('page_master')->where('id',$page_id)->first();
    return view('edit-list',compact('listEdit'));
}
```

and its route:

```
 $router->get('/edit-List/{id}', 'AjaxController@EditList');
```

The above code successfully shows me the edit page where I will perform the update.
My next step is update record:

The controller method

```
public function updatePage($id)
{
    $updatePage = $this->page->updatePage($id);
    if(!$updatePage)
    {
        $resultArray = ['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Page not exist!'];
        return Response::json( $resultArray, 400);
    }
    else{
        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Page updated !'];
        return Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }

}
```

and its routes:

```
  Route::post('update/list/{id}',['uses' => 'ApiController@updatePage']);
```

Now when i click on update record it shows me `the page does not exist` even though the page is there in database but always showing the page does not exist page.

What should I change to make the routes work properly?

```
           public function updatePage($id)
{
    $updatePage = self::find($id);
    if (is_null($updatePage)) {
        return false;
    }
    $input = Input::all();
    $updatePage->fill($input);
    $updatePage->save();
    return $updatePage;
}
```

Comment: Does your `$this->page exist`? is it initialized? or is it null. Also, can you post the `updatePage()` code you're calling in `$this->page->updatePage`

Comment: public function updatePage($id)
    {
        $updatePage = self::find($id);
        if (is_null($updatePage)) {
            return false;
        }
        $input = Input::all();
        $updatePage->fill($input);
        $updatePage->save();
        return $updatePage;
    }

Comment: This is my method code

Comment: I also edit in my question

Comment: can you show the button code for the view `edit-list` what you use to build up the ajax query? You must be passing an id there, but I don't see it passed to the view.

Comment: This is my button code when i click it show me the page where i will update values:

Comment: <li><a href="{{url('edit-List/'.$value->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit Page</a></li>

Comment: and i also post a route for this

Comment: You're new here. When someone asks for extra code, always edit it in your question. Also, I want to see the button or link that triggers the call to `update/list/`. not the one that works.